# Movie where a man invents a spray that removes sounds

Tags: story-identification, movie

I believe that I watched this movie in the mid-90s, but I think it was black and white. What I remember is that a man and a boy were trying to escape from somewhere. The man got the idea to make a spray that could eliminate all sounds in the area. I think that he got the idea from a spray of odor remover. When the man and boy try to escape they go into a room with a bunch of kids playing instruments and use the spray: the kids are banging cymbals and drums, and playing their various instruments, but there is no sound. The man and boy eventually escape.

Comment: I've got two hyperactive grandkids who permanently live with us, they've both got drum kits - I really wish that there was such an invention!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this movie is *[The 5,000 Fingers of Dr. T](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_5,000_Fingers_of_Dr._T.)* (1953) which is the only feature film written by Dr. Seuss.

The young protagonist must take piano lessons, which he hates, and dreams a surreal dream of escape. The noise removing spray is part of the boy's dream.

[image]

Comment: I am astonished. I'd always associated this with Seuss but for some reason my searching always failed me and I assumed I was misremembering. How did you find this?

Comment: @Gamerjosh I'd seen the movie listed in TV Guide when I was young, but it never showed on my local stations. Years later I borrowed a VHS copy from my library.

Comment: It's not actually a spray - it's a bottle of liquid that, when opened, absorbs all sound from the vicinity and replaces it with silly sound effects.  Also, it's somehow explosive - described in the film as being "*very* atomic".  But yeah, definitely fits.  A great movie.  The villainous piano teacher, Dr. Terwilliker, is played by Hans Conried, also known for being the voice of Snidely Whiplash and Captain Hook - but if you thought he was a Large Ham in those roles, well, you ain't seen nothing yet.